# Mandroid error XA9005: User code size, 2945919 bytes, is larger than 131072 and requires a Business (or higher) License.

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I just finished downloading and installing Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise with Update 2 via my `MSDN` subscription. I saw the news from Build indicating that `Xamarin` is now free with Visual Studio Enterprise, but I am getting the following Licensing error:

> ```
> 1>------ Build started: Project: App1.Droid, Configuration: Debug Any CPU -----
>
> 1>C:\Users\Parrot\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Droid\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml : warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported  
> 1> App1.Droid -> 
>
> C:\Users\Parrot\Projects\App1\App1\App1.Droid\bin\Debug\App1.Droid.dll
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(379,5): mandroid error XA9005: User code size, 2945919 bytes, is larger than 131072 and requires aáBusinessá(or higher) License.  
> 1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(379,5): mandroid error XA9006: Using type `Android.Runtime.JNIEnv` requiresáBusinessá(or higher) License.  
> ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========  
> ========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
> ```

I've already tried logging out of Visual Studio and restarting it, but I still see this error.

Comment: Try a full reinstallation of the Xamarin software. Ensure your VS is updated to Update 2, and then remove the Xamarin software via Control Panel and download it again: https://www.xamarin.com/download

If that does not work, please post your Xamarin VS Verison Information from (Help -> About Visual Studio)

Comment: No need of full reinstall etc. Just update your Xamarin to latest stable release. even if it is Vs 2015 update 1 , it is fine. Xamarin needs to be latest. Any Xamarin with 4.0.0.* has this issue

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't be getting licensing errors with the newest tooling. If you already had Xamarin installed in Visual Studio before updating to Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, you may be on an older version of Xamarin for Visual Studio.

Only the latest version of Xamarin for Visual Studio will allow you to work in Visual Studio without a traditional Xamarin license. Can you ensure that you have version 4.0.3.214 installed? You should be able to find that information via "Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio -> Copy Info [button]"

Any version older than that will need to be updated. You can follow the instructions for Visual Studio [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/) to check your updater channel and force a check for updates.

Version 4.0.3.214 is currently in both Beta and Stable channels.

Comment: Ran into the same issue. Uninstalled, reinstalled. Got the latest version. Still get the error. :(

Comment: As it turns out, it wasn't the Windows bits that were causing the error -- I had neglected to update the Mac bits.

Comment: Does this version make sense?Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01586
Installed Version: Community
Xamarin   99.0.0.1562 (a9dd59b)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Android.
Xamarin.Android   6.0.99.544 (8f34ab4)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.Android.
Xamarin.iOS   9.7.0.316 (c8540f9)
Visual Studio extension to enable development for Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: @MotKohn - the version you have installed is an alpha preview from March 10th 2016. You're going to need to update to a newer version.

Answer (score 2):

Also ensure that you have installed the latest Xamarin bits on the Mac build host that you are using. The error may come from there instead of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I use Visual Studio 2015 Update 2, but in Tool => Option => Xamarin => Other i choose Alpha and Visual Studio installed Alpha version. Now i choose Stable => Visual studio auto install Xamarin Stable version => Work like charm! :)
[image]

Comment: I don't see how this update tab will address the question.