# Using type "Android.Runtime.JNIEnv" requires a Business (or higher) License in Xamarin for VS 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

As of today, Microsoft and Xamarin have made Xamarin free to use for small teams.
Upon creating a Xamarin Forms app I am unable to run the Android version of my app and am given the error messages :

```
Using type `Android.Runtime.JNIEnv` requiresáBusinessá(or higher) License
```

Would this possibly have to do with the fact I had recently installed the starter edition already on this machine? I'm not sure why I'm getting this error considering I have updated Xamarin to the latest version and all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just posted an answer to a similar looking issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347633/warning-xa0101-content-build-action-is-not-supported). Are you perhaps hitting the same thing?