# Xamarin Free says I exceeded the code size

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Accordingly to March 31, 2016 post in [Xamarin blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/)

> As of today, we are including Xamarin in Visual Studio at no extra cost.
>   Xamarin will be in every edition of Visual Studio, including the widely-available Visual Studio Community Edition, which is free for individual developers, open source projects, academic research, education, and small professional teams. Develop and publish native apps for iOS and Android with C# or F# from directly within Visual Studio with no limits on app size.

I've installed the latest version of Xamarin on Windows 10 using **Alpha** channel and created new Blank App (Xamarin.Forms Portable) in VS Community 2015.

Project is building fine but making deploy of IOS project on emulator I see the following error:

```
User code size, 1418240 bytes, is larger than 131072 bytes and requires
a??Business??(or higher) license.   App1.iOS
```

So am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347633/warning-xa0101-content-build-action-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Alpha channel has not been updated to support the new licensing that was brought into effect recently.

Switching back to the Stable channel will resolve this. A guide for how to do this can be found here:

https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/cross-platform/ide/change_updates_channel/

Answer (score 0):

I would switch to the stable channel and download the latest update.  It should solve your issue