# Visual Studio 2017 won't build Xamarin Android project. XA9005 User Code Size error. Requires Business License

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I've uninstalled and reinstalled Xamarin and I continue to get this error.  Is this a bug? I thought that Xamarin license now came with VS.

```
    Error XA9005: User code size, 217070 bytes, is larger than 131072 and requires a Business (or higher) License. (1, 1)
```

Comment: It looks like it might be a bug. https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/ states: "Develop and publish native apps for iOS and Android with C# or F# from directly within Visual Studio with no limits on app size." ... you should probably report it.. They'll respond and let you know if it's a bug, or point you to the correct docs if not.

Comment: @Aaron, Yes, I agree.  Trying to find the right channel for reporting this and getting help.  The phone number I found on the Xamarin site was useless.

Comment: You could read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347633/mandroid-error-xa9005-user-code-size-2945919-bytes-is-larger-than-131072-and

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT.  Yup.  Read that.  Not really much help.  My next step is to try uninstalling and reinstalling and hope that works, but people have commented that it makes no difference.  

I posted this as a new question because all the others dealt with VS 2015. Wanted to see if anyone had this issue in VS 2017.

Answer (score 0):

Well, uninstalling and reinstalling VS 2017 and Xamarin seem to have corrected the problem for now.  What a total pain and hours of lost time.

If anyone ever has a better solution, please post it, as it may help others, or me next time.

Cheers!